# Workflow Reminder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have custom list - Expiry contract with column 'signing date' and 'expiry date'. I have a workflow for 1 month reminder, the workflow shown below.
my question is how to edit the workflow with 3 month, 2 month, 1 month reminder before expiry date?

[image]

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with the same approach as your workflow above.

You could create 2 more variables, such as ReminderDate60 (2 months reminder) and ReminderDate90 (3 months reminder), and also check the date of signing to those two variables with similar approach as you have done with 1 month reminder above.

Another way to do this (if you have access to visual studio) is to create a custom timer job which runs everyday and checks the above condition for each item whose workfow status is not completed yet.